# Cannot find module “@angular/animations for Ionic 3

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I’m added this calendar (https://market.ionic.io/themes/ionic-calendar-week )for my Application ,But I had some error
How to fix it ,
this is my
im try to installed but not work `npm install @angular/animations@latest --save`

**package.jason**

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {

    "@angular/common": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "angular-percent-circle-directive": "^1.1.1",
    "angular-svg-round-progressbar": "^1.1.1",
    "cordova-android": "6.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.16",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
    "ion2-calendar": "^2.1.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.7.1",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionic3-calendar": "^1.1.6",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.19.1",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

error

> Runtime Error Cannot find module "@angular/animations" Stack Error:
>   Cannot find module "@angular/animations"
>       at Object. (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:132377:7)
>       at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
>       at Object.356 (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1179:95)
>       at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
>       at Object.337 (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1159:70)
>       at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
>       at webpackJsonpCallback (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:26:23)
>       at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1:1

Comment: Looks like a typo but you are missing double code in front of `@angular/animations` under dependencies it should be `"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.1"`

Comment: sir im 5 time try this installed to `npm install @angular/animations@latest --save` all ready installed but not` displayed "dependencies": { "@angular/animations": "^5.0.1"`

Comment: it means your package is not installing correctly check out command line if there are some errors while installing

Comment: @jitender Sir now its work :D Im reinstalled `npm install ionic` AND AFTER INSTALLED AGAIN `npm install @angular/animations@latest --save`

Comment: Glad it helped [connect me on linkedin](https://in.linkedin.com/in/jitender-kundu)...

Comment: Thanks for the guide me sir, I'll add you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

now its work Im reinstalled `npm install ionic` AND AFTER INSTALLED AGAIN `npm install @angular/animations@latest --save`